# nodejs :extract just one entry from a zip file

Tags: node.js, unzip, adm-zip

I m trying to find a performant way to extract just one entry from a zip file.
The command line unzip is just working orders of magnitude faster.

I tried adm-zip which has a method to pick out an entry.

I tried yauzl - and I used the readEntry cursor and checked each path for a filename match.

Are there some options for nodejs that are at least in the same region in performance?

Thanks